# VBA AddDataField CubeFields - Error 1004

Tags: vba, excel

I'm stumped...been building a PowerPivot sales report over the past few months and teaching myself VBA and DAX along the way. My report has several pre-configured views that can be chosen by VBA buttons, which work completely fine until you close the workbook and re-open it. Every time the workbook is opened for the first time - the VBA code errors out on the first AddDataField CubeFields line of code. It's as if excel does not pre-calculate the measure I am trying to add.

If I manually remove/add a value in the pivot table and then run the VBA code, it runs flawlessly. If I open PowerPivot manage data window and then close it, the VBA code runs perfectly fine. Something about manually changing values in the pivot table or simply opening the PowerPivot data tab, prompts Excel to pre-calculate all measures. Here is the exact line of code that gets hung up every time:

```
Worksheets("Dealer Install Sales").PivotTables("PivotTable1").AddDataField Worksheets("Dealer Install Sales").PivotTables( _
"PivotTable1").CubeFields("[Measures].[Sum of INVOICE_QTY]"), _
"PIECES"
```

How do I force excel to automatically calculate all measures upon opening the workbook?

Answer (score 0):

I think what might be going on is the behaviour described in this [joy-of-data](https://www.joyofdata.de/blog/controlling-powerpivot-and-pivot-tables-with-vba/) blog post.

To paraphrase, a measure used in a pivot table which was created outside it, is "forgotten" in certain circumstances. A solution is to create a new measure *within* the pivot table field list (right click in field list and add measure), which simply references the original measure, e.g. =[measure name].

In your code, refer to the new name of measure, and when you do this, the data model should be stimulated into returning the value of the original measure, instead of falling over.